# Symbolic link to text editor (Sublime) on Mac

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2

I'm following along with this tutorial on how to use Sublime text editor https://tutsplus.com/lesson/services-and-opening-sublime-from-the-terminal/ . It gives instructions to enter the following command to enable opening of Sublime in the terminal.

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

After creating that link, it says I should be able to do

```
subl .
```

to open all the files in a folder in Sublime. However, when I do it, it says

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

My system says the file exists

```
 ln: /bin/subl: File exists
```

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Create a new link to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```